# Why is eToro asking to deposit 500 if the stock value is only 50?

Tags: stocks, trading, online-brokerage, online-trading

I am starting to try out some platforms for trading and investing and I was surprised to see that eToro was asking me to **either use leverage (which I don't want) or take a minimum position of 500 USD**, when the price of the stock I'm trying to buy is about 50 USD. Same happens if I try to buy 1 share of Netflix which right now is about 339 USD, it asks for a min position of 500 USD.

Does anyone know what this is about ? If this is a min position requirement when not using leverage I think it sucks ...

[image]

Comment: Brokerage firms have the right to have more restrictive requirements than regulations permit.  For example, higher  minimum account size, higher margin requirements, investment/trading experience, option level approval requirements, etc.  This minimum trade size might be one of them at EToro.  Call the, for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's their required amount when not using leverage, which kind of pressures you to use leverage ...